# Getting wrong results in my word counting program

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make an app that counts how many times the words in the string appear. For example if I have the string "I want because I want" I would like to see the results "2,2,1".
But the results I am getting are "1,1,1,1,1".

This is the part of my program that I think is faulty and relevant to the question:

```
Scanner counter = new Scanner(text);
int currentword = 0;


String[] thewords = new String[10001];
int[] thenumbers = new int[10000];
String usedwords = "";

while (counter.hasNext()) {
    String nextstring = counter.next();

    for(int temp = 0; temp < thewords.length;temp++) {

        if (thewords[temp] == null) {
            thewords[currentword] = nextstring;
            currentword++;
            thenumbers[currentword]++;
            break;
        }
        else  if (thewords[temp].equals(nextstring)) {
            thenumbers[temp]++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I am getting wrong results because I have run through the code many times without succeeding to find the problem.

Any help is appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: In your first if you first increment currentword and after that you increment thenumbers[currentword]. I think you should change the order of these two lines.

Comment: try switching from using the "++" operator to "x = x + 1". after doing that, see if you can figure out why it did something different ;)

Comment: Thank you @mayamar. You are a genius, it worked :)

Comment: @AyhamSYR consider using a `HashMap` to solve this problem. The distinct words being the key and the word count for the corresponding word being the value.

Comment: @Shankha057 thank you but it worked now. I don't need it to be super efficient it is only a school assignment

Comment: Maybe you don't need it to be super efficient (now), but that knowledge might come in handy in the future

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways how to reduce a word array to a word frequency map. Here is one:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    String text = "I want because I want";

    String[] words = text.split("\\s+"); // split by whitespace
    Set<String> uniqueWords = Arrays.stream(words).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    final Map<String, Long> wordFrequencies = uniqueWords.stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                Function.identity(),
                word -> Arrays.stream(words).filter(w -> w.equals(word)).count()));

    wordFrequencies.forEach((word, frequency) -> {
      System.out.println(String.format("%s: %d", word, frequency));
    });
```

This code prints out:

```
want: 2
I: 2
because: 1
```